# Setting up WebSockets with Django Channels on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, django-channels

I'm trying to set up WebSockets on AWS instance. Since I use Django for my webapp, for WebSocket support I use [Django Channels](https://github.com/django/channels). I deployed the app using AWS Elastic Beanstalk, but I get the error:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://xxx.elasticbeanstalk.com/' failed: Error
>   during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200.

After some research I found that I need to set up TCP on port 80 and SSL on 443 instead of HTTP and HTTPS, which I did, but without change, I still get the error. I also disabled load balancing across multiple Availability Zones with no success.

I don't know if the EB config file makes problem, since I have only `WSGIPath` set and not the ASGI which is used by Daphine and Channels. There is no `ASGIPath` tag to try this.

I found an article about new [Application Load Balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-application-load-balancer/), but since it is a quite new service, I wasn't able to find anything for WebSockets with Django. Django Channels is also new, so not many questions and posts about it as well.

Comment: I suppose the ALB is the only way, because with the SSL protocol listner in the classic LB, the session stickiness and X-Forwaded headers won't be forwarded as will result in the proxy server redirect loop. Doc is here, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-listener-config.html

Comment: DId you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: No. I asked a couple of times a local aws community on meetups, without success. I am not working on that project anymore, but would still be pleased if someone provided an answer.